Is it possible to share content between multiple volumes using IntelliJ IDEA CE and TeXify and what would be the way to do this?
On Linux I was using TeXStudio and could fairly easily share content between different documents. But now I need to work on a Mac computer with the M1 chip (Silicon) and TeXStudio does not exist natively for this environment.
That's why I decided to use IntelliJ IDEA CE with the TeXify plugin to work in my new environment.
Considering the following directory tree:
.
└── IdeaProjects/
    ├── biennal/
    │   └── common/
    │       ├── template/
    │       │   └── main-template.tex
    │       ├── biblical/
    │       │   ├── Gn/
    │       │   │   ├── Gn_01_01-20.tex
    │       │   │   └── Gn_01_21-27.tex
    │       │   └── Ex/
    │       │       ├── Ex_01_01-15.tex
    │       │       └── Ex_02_08-22.tex  
    │       └── patres/
    │           ├── Agustin/
    │           │   ├── Agustin_PL038_0636.tex
    │           │   └── Agustin_PL038_1016.tex
    │           └── Ambrosio/
    │               ├── Ambrosio_CCL014_0165.tex
    │               └── Ambrosio_CCL064_0052.tex 
    ├── volume-01/
    │   └── src/
    │       └── main.tex
    ├── volume-02/
    │   └── src/
    │       └── main.tex
    ├── volume-03/
    │   └── src/
    │       └── main.tex
    └── volume-04/
        └── src/
            └── main.tex   

I want to share between the different volumes:

The configuration of documents, commands and environments, which are defined in common/main-template.tex

That content that can appear more than once in the different volumes. That content is located in the folders common/patres/ and common/biblical


My question is, is it possible to do this and what would be the best way: using modules, using gradle? Is there an example of this?
Another reason why I want to do this, is because I need to generate a global index of all the volumes with the content that is located in patres and in biblical.
EMV
biennal/common/template/main-template.tex:
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

volume-01/src/main.tex:
\input{../../biennal/common/template/main-template}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \input{../../biennal/common/biblical/Gn/Gn_01_21-27}
    \input{../../biennal/common/patres/Agustin/Agustin_PL038_0636}
    \lipsum
\end{document}

The code works, generating a document with the content, although the IDE also displays the message: Command requires lipsum package

you question isn't really very clear but I would start by removing all the ../../ which just make your documents fragile and tied to that directory structure, just have \input{Agustin_PL038_0636} in the same way you have \documentclass{article} without having /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls  just ensure that your IDE sets up TEXINPUTS=.//: in the environment then any file found recursively in a subdirectory of the project will be found

Texstudio works fine on mac M1, I use it every day.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Maybe you're using it with Rosetta? According to this it is not compatible.

https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/tag/4.8.4 has a build for M1

@DavidCarlisle I have put this in the environment variable:  TEXINPUTS=.//:, but it does not find the files. In short, what I want is to be able to use files outside the folders of those projects from within each project (volume-01, volume-02 ...). Or to know if there is a better way to relate those projects using modules or Gradle (IntelliJ IDEA).

... and why not use rosetta? One hardly notices a difference and gets a good editor in return.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry, but I don't want to use Rosetta. Can you confirm that this version of TeXStudio works without Rosetta?

use TEXINPUTS=/absolute/path/to/top/of/your/project//:  ( . would work if your editor runs tex from a suitable place but the absolute path to the root should work anywhere)

@A.Cedano Try it :)

@DavidCarlisle Adding TEXINPUTS=~/IdeaProjects/biennal//: finds the file, but a "file not found" message persists in the IDE.

I can only help with the tex side of things, the ide setup I don't know and is probably off topic for this site, sorry


TeXStudio does not exist natively for this environment.

TeXstudio offers builds for M1 macs, see the release page https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases
Testing this with Silicon Info will show you:

There is no reason to abstain from using TeXstudio on a mac, no matter what chip it has.

Thanks a lot. I installed the native M1 version and it's working fine.
